# Solidity Compiler - Error: Identifier already declared

Tags: solidity, solc, compilation, error, compiler

**Full source code of the file 'Test.sol' :**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


contract Mortal{

    address owner;

    string ownerInfo = "Contract Owner name XYZ";

    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill () public {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }

    function ownerInfo() public view returns (string) {
        return ownerInfo;
    }

}


contract Test is Mortal {

    string message = "Hello World!";

    constructor () public {
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns (string){
        return message;
    }
}
```

**Compiler Error:**

```
myMac:solidity admin$ solc Test.sol
Test.sol:21:2: Error: Identifier already declared.
    function ownerInfo() public view returns (string) {
 ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Test.sol:9:2: The previous declaration is here:
    string ownerInfo = "Contract Owner name XYZ";
    ^------------------------------------------^
```

I don't see any *duplicate* declaration of `ownerInfo`. Any idea, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Hari GTT Psicolabis' answer is right, but that means that you have to specify the `ownerInfo` field as `public` to get the benefit of a public getter.

```
string public ownerInfo = "Contract Owner name XYZ";
```

the alternative, is to change the name of your function.

Comment: You are right, i don't know why i though it was already public

Comment: I forgot to change the method name to 'getOwnerName'!
And happy to know additional information on 'automatically generated getters' in Solidity.

@mirg, **Changing the name alone works**:
`string ownerInfo = "x";
function getOwnerInfo() public view returns (string) { return ownerInfo; }`.

@hari-gtt-psicolabis, Thanks! Just declaring variable as `public` also works:
`string public ownerInfo = "x";
function ownerInfo() public view returns (string) { return ownerInfo; }`.
I accepted @mirg's answer, since exposing attribute as 'public' isn't a desired solution. But, have upvoted :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is because the method and the property have the same name. Since solidity automatically creates a public getter function for every public variable in the contract, you don't need `function ownerInfo() public view returns (string)`